# NMOS is high when gate is low

Tags: nmos, circuits, dram

I’m trying to simulate DRAM with N-MOSFETs with row and column selecting logic. When I select my column, which is connected to the source of an N-MOSFET, the N-MOSFETs in that column all turn on, even when the gate is low.

I’ve simulated and attached one N-MOSFET that has a grounded gate and source at VDD. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: body diode .....

Comment: @sss what program are you using?

Comment: pspice! @jsotola you were right, its the body diode.

Answer (score 0):

You need the right MOSFET model. You could use an ideal one with no leakage and no body diode for starters. Then you could move on to a simulated silicon model. Check the current though the FET also, that should help check the leakage.